# Need to pick up the SUM OF Tax Amount for the highest Sequence number Per Year, Per SSN, Per employer

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider Employee table:

```
Employerid ssn  year  Seqnumber     q1taxamt   q2taxamt     q3taxamt     q4taxamt
1004       101  2013    1             2000       0            0             0
1004       101  2013    2             2000       100          0             0
1004       101  2013    3             2000       100          200           0
1004       101  2013    4             2000       100          200           300
1004       102  2013    1             3000       0            0             0
1004       102  2013    2             3000       200          0             0
1004       102  2013    3             3000       200          300           0
1004       102  2013    4             3000       200          300           400
1004       102  2013    5             3000       200          300           400
```

Here the  transformation rule is we need to pick the highest Seqnumber with respect to each ssn per year per
Employerid and the amounts.

i.e for 10004 for sum(q1taxamt) is 2000 +3000 = 5000

The Logic is ssn 101 has highest seq number of 4 and ssn 102 has highest seq number of 5 so we need to pick those values wrt to employerid

Example:
Want to check for q1taxamt: 2000 +3000 = 5000

Want to check for q4taxamt: 300 +400 = 700

output must be:

```
Employerid  YEAR     q1taxamt   q2taxamt     q3taxamt     q4taxamt     
10004        2013     5000        300          500           700
```

The below query is generating wrong result:

```
Select
    Sum(E1.q1taxamt) q1taxamt,
    Sum(E1.q2taxamt) q2taxamt,
    Sum(E1.q3taxamt) q3taxamt,
    Sum(E1.q4taxamt) q4taxamt,
    E1.Employerid,
    E1.YEAR
from Employee E1
join
(
    select 
        E.Employerid,
        MAX(E.seqnumber) seqnumber,
        E.YEAR
    from Employee E
    group by E.Employerid,E.SSn,E.year
)E2
on E1.Employerid=E2.Employerid
AND E1.YEAR=E2.YEAR
and E1.seqnumber=E2.Taxseqnumber
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `row_number()`:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by E.Employerid, E.SSn, E.year
                                order by e.seqnumber desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from Employee e
     ) e
where seqnum = 1;
```

For best performance, you want an index on `Employee(EmployerId, SSN, seqnumber desc)`.

Comment: Taking long time to execute, can we have any other performance tip

Answer (score 0):

You missing `SSN` join predicate between `E1` and `E2` thats why you are getting wrong result. I think this might be faster than `Row_Number` method.

```
Select
    Sum(E1.q1taxamt) q1taxamt,
    Sum(E1.q2taxamt) q2taxamt,
    Sum(E1.q3taxamt) q3taxamt,
    Sum(E1.q4taxamt) q4taxamt,
    E1.Employerid,
    E1.YEAR
from Employee E1
join
(
    select 
        E.Employerid,
        E.SSn,
        MAX(E.seqnumber) seqnumber,
        E.YEAR
    from Employee E
    group by E.Employerid,E.SSn,E.year
)E2
on E1.Employerid=E2.Employerid
AND E1.YEAR=E2.YEAR
AND E1.SSN = E2.SSN --Here
and E1.seqnumber=E2.Taxseqnumber
```